# 2D Bullet Class Unity

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, trigonometry

Where is the error in this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BulletScript : MonoBehaviour {
private float angle;
private bool initialized=false;
private float speed=.01f;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {
    if(initialized)
    {
        Vector3 v = new Vector3((speed*Mathf.Cos(angle)),(speed*Mathf.Sin(angle)),0);
        transform.position+=v;
    }
}
public void initialize(Vector2 startPos, Vector2 targetPos)
{
    transform.position=new Vector3(startPos.x,startPos.y,transform.position.z);
    angle = (Mathf.Atan2(targetPos.y-startPos.y,targetPos.x-startPos.x))*Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    print(angle);
    initialized=true;
}
}
```

The angle is calculated correctly. However, the bullet travels in a random direction.
If angle=45 degrees, the bullet moves away at about a 45 degree angle.
If angle=90 degrees, the bullet moves away at about a 110 degree angle.
If angle=180 degrees, the bullet moves away at about a 225 degree angle.
If angle=360 degrees, the bullet moves away at about a 130 degree angle.
It is almost as if the greater the angle, the greater the incorrect offset is.

Comment: The Mathf.Cos function takes a degree in radians. So, don't worry about converting it to degrees in your initialize function.

Comment: You sir, are gentleman and a scholar. Problem solved.